# how to get index in selected item on change event (select box)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 4 dropdown in my page .I want to know which dropdown is selected or changed using index,.But every time i am getting `0` index.here is my code

https://jsbin.com/fapahosenu/1/edit?html,js,output

```
$(function(){
  function dropdownChangeHandler(){
    console.log($(this).index())
  }
  $('[data-dropdown="dropdowns_js"]').on('change',dropdownChangeHandler);
})
```

this is not I am wanted ..I want if I change first dropdown it gives me `0`.
I change second dropdown it gives me `1`.I change third dropdown it gives me `2`

Comment: `console.log(event.target.selectedIndex)`

Comment: You should explain the question correctly. Please explain what are you going to achieve by getting which select is triggered. That will narrow down the question and encourage others to give an optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you're getting the `index()` from the `select` yet they are not siblings, hence they all return `0`.

To fix this pass a selector to `index()` which is the group of elements you wish to find the index in, like this:

```js
$('[data-dropdown="dropdowns_js"]').on('change', function() {
  var index = $(this).index('[data-dropdown="dropdowns_js"]');  
  console.log(index);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span>
  <select class="dropdowns_js"  data-dropdown="dropdowns_js" data-key="bank">
    <option selected="true" disabled="true" value="0">Select Bank</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</span>
<span>
  <select class="dropdowns_js"  data-dropdown="dropdowns_js" data-key="state">
    <option selected="true" disabled="true" value="0">Select State</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</span>
<span>
  <select class="dropdowns_js"  data-dropdown="dropdowns_js" data-key="district">
    <option selected="true" disabled="true" value="0">Select District</option>
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
</span>
```

Comment: I want dropdown index if i change sate dropdown .it gives me ``1`

Comment: Ah, now it's clearer what you're attempting to do I updated the question for you

Answer (score 0):

Add the event onclick and pass the value with `function dropdownChangeHandler(1)` like this

Answer (score 0):

Try with below function it will give you the selected drop-down index. Please mark as answer, if your problem resolve with my solution

```
function dropdownChangeHandler(){
  $('.dropdowns_js').each(function(a,b){       
    if($(this).is(":focus"))
    {
      console.log(a);
    }
  }); 
}
```

If you select **state** drop-down, It will give you 1 as selected index